# MEAN stack how to send a user a file

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, meanjs

I have some code on the express controller that looks like this:

```
// Correct file path and write data
var currentDate = new Date();
var storagePath = path.join(__dirname,'../../public/reports/', 'Risk-Log.csv');
var source = es.readArray(riskLogs);
source.pipe(jsonCSV.csv(options)).pipe(fs.createWriteStream(storagePath));
console.log('Completed csv export to ' + storagePath);
// Send file back
res.sendFile(storagePath);
```

In my angular view (`log.client.view.html`) I have the following:

```
<a href="/#!/my-logs/download" class="btn btn-default">Download CSV</a>
```

When I click that button... The file gets generated properly, but the file never gets sent back to the user (that they can tell).

If I look at the console debugger I get the following:

```
Resource {$promise: Object, $resolved: false, $get: function, $save: function, $query: function…}
```

I haven't done any routing with Angular or anything special since it's hitting the Node (express) controller and generating the file. I'm wondering if this is something that I should be doing in Angular?

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the user clicks that button the CSV downloads.

Any help would be MUCH appreciated.

Comment: There are two options, you have to either add the HTML5 `download` attribute to the anchor to instantiate a download, or send the proper headers to start a download -> `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Risk-log.csv"` ... etc

Comment: I tried the download attribute and it didn't work. I'll try setting the content

Comment: the download attrib won't work with a hash-based url in the href...

Comment: Hmm that makes sense. I couldn't get it to work with `Content-Disposition` either. I will try a direct route without the `#`. However, I'm used to that from the angular routing.

Comment: So... it's downloading a CSV now, but it's blank. Is that because the `fs.createWriteStream()` hasn't finished yet?

Comment: Ok, the CSV was blank because the data hadn't finished writing. Just need to figure out what event callback to wire up to and I'm good. Anyone want to post the answer for credit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since using express res.send() is a buffer.... you have to send in the content type like so:

```
res.set('Content-Type', 'text/csv');
res.set('Content-Disposition', 'attachment');
res.send(csv); // csv object created with json-csv npm module
```

Big thanks to all those who commented on this!